# Prove for each pair of integers $j, k : k > 0$, there exists a $q : j - qk > 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> Prove for each pair of integers $j, k : k > 0$, there exists a $q : j - qk > 0$.

I began by writing out all three cases, **i.e.** $C_1 \to j > k$, $C_2 \to j = k$, and $C_3 \to j < k$.

For $C_1$, $q = 1$ yields the desired result.

For $C_2$, $j > qj$ is possible if $q = -1$.

For $C_3$, $q = -1$ works as well.

The book's answer, however, is

> Take $q = -|j| - 1$

Is there something wrong with my proof? Is it still correct?

Comment: The proof of case 3 is wrong.

Comment: In case $C_2$ there are other $q$. In case $C_3$ putting $q=-1$ does not necessarily work.

Comment: I see, taking $q$ to be absolutely greater than $1$ in case 3 yields the result we want.

Answer (score 0):

Here $j$ is any integer.
Suppose $j<0$,
The least no. subtracted to $j$ in this case to get result positive is: $-(|j|+1)$
As, $j-(-(|j|+1))=j+(|j|+1)>0$
here $-(|j|+1)$ can be multiplied by any positive integer $k$, and the result is still positive.
$j-(-(|j|+1)k)>0$
suppose $j\geq0$,
$j-(-(|j|+1))=j+|j|+1>0$
the result is still valid if we multiply $-(|j|+1)$ by $k$ conditioned as above.
hence $q=-(|j|+1)$ is one of the general solution.
Also it is obvious that being given $j$ as integer, $q$ is also integer.
One is able to deduct this $q$ if we focus on: The least no. subtracted to $j$, in the negative case above.